# ExpressJS Middleware Method to make variable available in other (module) files

Tags: node.js, express

I am playing around with making a NodeJS app that combines REST API functionality with MongoDB CRUD persistence.  I'm pretty new to NodeJS.

Right now I've managed to connect to the Database and figured out that the rest of my code belongs inside the callback - ie only process REST request after the DB is up and available.

The challenge I'm running into in this case is understanding how to "attach" the 'client' (from mongodb.connect) to the 'request'. I need to somehow make it available in other files because I want to keep my routes separate as a best practice.

The same question applies to any variables in the main server.js file which I need to be able to access in my modules.
Here is the relevant code:

```
//server.js
const express = require('express')
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const routes = require('./routes')

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB'
let app = express();
app.use(logger('dev'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

mongodb.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true},(error, dbClient) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`Error: ${error}`)
        process.exit(1)
    }

    //connected
    console.log(`Connected to mongoDB`)
    //what do I do here to make sure my routes can access dbClient?
    app.get('/accounts', routes.getAccounts(req, res) )

    app.listen(3000)
})


//./routes/index.js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const errorhandler = require('errorhandler')
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const logger = require('morgan')

module.exports = {
    getAccounts: (req, res) => {
        console.log("in getAccounts")
        //how can I use dbClient in here?
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!
My apologies if anything about my post isn't according to the normal standards, I'm brand new here!  All critique appreciated, coding and otherwise!

Comment: This article will help you. Use connection pooling. Do not create a new connection for each incoming request. https://www.compose.com/articles/connection-pooling-with-mongodb/

Comment: @MattLong Thanks for the tip, I didn't know such a thing existed but it makes a lot of sense.  Raises a lot of questions too and I will dive deeper into the docs.